# scrape App Store web data

Tags: text, web-access, data-acquisition, data-mining

I want to scrape the privacy information of an app on the web store page.
For example, the Tiktok app information looks like this:

[image]

[tiktok on us app store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiktok/id835599320)

I found that it's easy to scrape that information

```
dat = Import["https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiktok/id835599320", 
  "Data"]

dat[[2, 1, 3]]

{{" Contact Info ", " Identifiers "}, {" Purchases ", 
  " Financial Info ", " Location ", " Contact Info ", " Contacts ", 
  " User Content ", " Search History ", " Browsing History ", 
  " Identifiers ", " Usage Data ", " Diagnostics "}, " Usage Data "}
```

However, when I click "See Details" (blue font), I get additional information on these settings:

[image]

How can I automatically scrape this information as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not easy as this modal window is hidden behind javascript manipulating the DOM and adding an element on the page. To get the modal to come up you have to visit the page with WebExecute and click on the button. I have tried various ways, `WebExecute[session, 
  "OpenPage" -> "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiktok/id835599320"];
WebExecute[session, 
  "JavascriptExecute" -> 
   "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"];
b= WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> ".app-privacy--modal"];
WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> b]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Neither does: `session = StartWebSession[];
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiktok/id835599320"];
WebExecute[session, "JavascriptExecute" -> "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);document.getElementById('modal-trigger-ember159').click();"];`

Comment: @flinty thanks, that was helpful. I made some progress using this code: `session = StartWebSession[]; WebExecute[session, 
 "OpenPage" -> "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tiktok/id835599320"]; button = WebExecute[session, 
  "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "#modal-trigger-ember159"]; WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> button];`  One problem is that the button name is sometimes different for other apps